# Store swapped new array inside nested for

Tags: python

How can I store this swapped new array inside nested for? After ending the loop this NEWstate becomes exactly like the given state a[2,1,5,0]. I was generating different states by swapping next elements. Need to store those swapped states.

```
def genrState(alist):
    
      NEW=[]
      print("Current state ", alist)
      i=0
      for x in alist:
        print("for", x, "index is  ", i)
        j=i
        for y in alist[i+1:]:
          if i < 10:
            alist[i] , alist[j+1] = alist[j+1], alist[i]
            print("generated", alist)
            NEWstate = alist
            print("NEW INSIDE", NEWstate ) 
          alist[i] , alist[j+1] = alist[j+1], alist[i]
          j=j+1`enter code here`
        i=i+1
        print("NEW", NEWstate )  
        print(alist)
    
    a=[2,1,5,0]
    genrState(a)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We also expect that you will trace the problem values through your code, and ask a *specific* question about the problem point.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `NEWstate = alist` you actually assign references. Both variables reference the same list in memory. If you want to create a copy of the list, use `NEWstate = alist[:]`